# Android Compatibility Library CursorLoader : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cursor is closed

Tags: android

I'm currently using a CursorLoader inside a Fragment with the Android Compatibility Library.
Almost every time, on the Droid 2 (I'm unable to reproduce on the Nexus One or the Sensation), it seems that the cursors are being closed too soon, which is causing various errors. Unfortunately the traces don't point anywhere helpful in my code (since the issue is why the Cursor is being closed, not when Android notices), so I'm really struggling to figure out what is going wrong. Has anyone else encountered this problem? (or have ideas what might be happening).

Some stack traces:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cursor is closed                                    
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:278)         
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:255)             
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:187)        
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:187)          
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:226)      
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1721)             
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)                            
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                            
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)                                        
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)                      
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                           
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                               
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)                   
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)           

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cursor is closed                                                          
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:278)                               
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:255)                                   
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:187)                              
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:187)                                
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:226)                            
    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:745)                                 
    at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1081)                             
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2207)                                       
    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3377)                                             
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)                                                 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)                                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)                                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)                                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)                                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)                                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)                                        
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1800)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1140)          
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2105)                                          
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1784)     
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1794)                                              
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)                                                              
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)                                            
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                                     
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)                                         
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)     

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cursor is closed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3438)                         
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3395)                         
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3378)                          
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:129)                                   
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2124)                              
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                               
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)                                                           
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)                                         
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                              
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                                  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)                   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)                                      
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)                                                     
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cursor is closed                                            
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:278)                            
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:255)                                
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:187)                           
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:187)                             
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:226)                         
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onSaveInstanceState(AbsListView.java:910)                              
    at android.widget.ListView.onSaveInstanceState(ListView.java:3687)                                   
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:6070)                                       
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:1197)                                
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(AdapterView.java:759)                        
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1184)                             
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:6053)                                              
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:1387)       
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1439)                
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:468)            
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1040)                                 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)            
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3420)                         
    ... 12 more
```

And for good measures, one that at least has a single line in my code:

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Access closed cursor                                   
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:217)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:27)       
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getBlob(CursorWrapper.java:143)                        
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getBlob(CursorWrapper.java:143)                        
    at com.testapp.TestFragment$1.setViewValue(TestFragment.java:84)                         
    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:131)  
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:257)               
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1319)                          
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1789)                            
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656)                                   
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1342)                              
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)                            
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1172)                            
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)                             
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)                             
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)                     
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)                    
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)                          
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)                             
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)                             
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7037)                                              
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1054)                           
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1736)                               
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                   
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)                                               
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)                             
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                      
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)       
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)                          
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update: Fixed, see my answer below**

Comment: Do you close the cursors by yourself?

Comment: No, I'm not opening or closing any of the cursors myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no cue what the problem is, but maybe this helps you pinning it down.

Create a `LoggedCursor` like this and setup cursor factory so your query gives you the LoggedCursor:

```
class LoggedCursor extends SQLiteCursor {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor closed by:", new RuntimeException("Stack trace"));
        super.close();
    }
}
```

The `RuntimeException` is created just to log the stack trace easily, not for throwing it. When the cursor is closed you'll see the trace in logs.

Hopefully, this helps figuring out when and by whom is it closed.

Comment: This was my initial thought as well, but I'm not actually constructing the cursor either. The entire cursor life-cycle is being handled by CursorLoader (which means I have no way to use the factory)

Comment: `CursorLoader` internally calls `ContentResolver.query(...)`, which in turn gets the `IContentProvider` matching your URI and executes `query(...)` on it. I don't know what your URI is, but I think it's possible to get the content provider of your URI before starting the loader, setup it with the cursor factory, and then start the loader. Or something like that.. Try getting content provider of your URI in debug mode to find out what class is returned so you could peek sources.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the underlying problem with this technique and have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 5):

I added logging as per JBM's suggestion and found the following:

I was using a subclass of CursorWrapper in my code.
On the Droid 2, someone added a finalizer to CursorWrapper which closes the underlying Cursor. That meant that whenever our wrapper was garbage collected, the Cursor was closed. This finalizer does not exist on other phones or in the Android source code. Guess someone thought they were being smart?

Fixed by overriding the finalizer in our CursorWrapper

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    // Do not remove this empty method. It is designed to prevent calls to super.
    // Fixes bug on Droid 2, where CursorWrapper finalizer closes the Cursor!
}
```

Comment: I am not using a CursorWrapper but I still get around 4 crash reports every day with Access Closed Cursor and they are coming from different phones. I can't reproduce it on my Nexus or Droid 1. Can you give more details on how you're using CursorWrapper. Do I need to extend CursorLoader?